# Guest Additions won't install in Windows 98

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, virtualbox, windows-98

I'm trying to set up file sharing between my Mac OS and Windows 98. I think the reason it's not working at the moment is that I haven't installed Guest Additions.

However, Guest Additions .iso is attached in Media Manager. It also looks fine in settings (see screengrabs, correct me if I'm wrong).

Settings:

[image: Settings]

In the virtual machine it doesn't automatically run, and if I try to manually run it nothing happens.

Bottom two .exe files don't run in W98, top .exe does nothing if you click on it:

[image: Bottom two .exe files don't run in W98, top .exe does nothing if you click on it]

Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect that the version of Guest Additions that your using doesn't support and OS as old as Win98.

Comment: Do you know if there is a version that does?

Comment: This question is not really about programming, you have better options of get it answered in [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 2):

VirtualBox Guest Additions don't exist for Windows 98.

VirtualBox Guest Additions work fine for Windows XP.

Modern Macs do not support SMB Network sharing with pre-XP operating systems like Windows 98 (my old Leopard machine did it fine, my new Mavericks machine won't do it at all), otherwise, you could switch on sharing with your Win98 virtual machine, and access files on there in OSX's Finder.

So what's the work around?
Make a WinXP virtual machine.
Either just use that instead, and use the Guest Additions to share files;
Or use WinXP as a middleman - and network your Win98 VM with your WinXP VM, and copy your files from Win98 to WinXP and then to OSX.
Most Win98 programs run fine in WinXP, so most people just use WinXP with Guest Additions, and leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew is right. VirtualBox Guest Additions don't exist for Windows 98, even if it exists there is no easy way to install it. And without Guest Addition shared folder will not going to work.

(when I try to execute the guest addition executable, its just throw error)

[image: Windows 98 guest additions]

There is no such issue with the Windows XP virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Guest Additions does not support Windows 98, only NT-based versions of Windows are supported. I hope this gets fixed soon. (Windows 98 is not NT-based. And also, any version of Windows that came after 2000, excluding ME, is definitely NT-based. So is NT, obviously.)